# No cargan los archivos en el servidor (Failed to load resource)

Tags: hosting, servidor

Este es el error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

Estaba desarrollando una plantilla html y en local todo va genial...
ahora que lo subí al servidor, los archivos JS y los de imagen no cargan, solo los CSS.

¿Alguién sabe que pudiese pasar? o ¿o cómo lo pudiese solucionar?

estos son lose archivos que no cargan..

```
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.min.js"></script>
```

Me meto en la ruta directamente y los archivos si existen, cargan sin problema

Comment: 403 es un error que indica que los ficheros pueden estar ahí (como confirmas), pero el servidor está bloqueando el acceso por algún motivo. ¿Hay un `.htaccess` o algo que requiera acceso especial al directorio js?

Comment: Los archivos, estan alojado en un subdominio, y no tiene htaccess, pero el dominio si tiene, no creo que eso afecte en algo.

Comment: Ok. ¿Puedes ver las cabeceras del fallo para ver qué error es exactamente? Puedes ver las cabeceras abriendo las consola del desarrollador, mirando el tráfico y pulsando en la petición que falla con 403.

Comment: Esta es la ruta!! http://demos.bagudesigns.com/themeforest/Bagu-Folder-CV-HTML-Template/index.html

Comment: El acceso directo a los ficheros no funciona. Si intentas ir al jQuery incluido ([enlace](http://demos.bagudesigns.com/themeforest/Bagu-Folder-CV-HTML-Template/js/jquery.min.js)) recibes el 403. Y también fallan algunas imágenes con el mismo error ¿Qué permisos tiene el directorio `js` en el servidor? Parece que puede ser un problema de permisos de acceso en el servidor